# libmysql.dll (mySql) and slow application perfomance on windows 10

Tags: mysql

I have an issue with old Delphi application. Application query counterpaty reference 1600 record , and use it on client side. When we test it on Windows 10 we've investigated that Counterparty form opened slowly than on Windows 7. The query executes 20 milliseconds on server, so I suspect something wrong with libmysql.dll
Is there any envinroment setting for win 10 to achieve better perfomance on Windows 10?
Compatibility mode for shortcut does not help. We don't have access to source code.

Comment: Please show us the SQL queries.

Comment: It's simple query like SELECT * FROM conterpatytab;

Comment: How many rows in that table?  Are there TEXT columns?  How long does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM conterpatytab` take?

Comment: Application query counterpaty reference 1600 record, there is only Varchar columns, there is no TEXT columns

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.